# Full Screen Overlay on Link Click

Tags: javascript, wordpress

A client has very specifically requested that their project page has a similar feel to [this](http://www.shedkm.co.uk/work/blue-hotel/). Whereby, you click a '+' button to display project information, in what I would say is a full-screen overlay window.

I'm familiar with HTML / CSS & while I have dabbled with PHP I have never touched JS. And I'm pretty sure that is what the developer of the above site has used here.

So, my questions are:

1. How do I achieve this outcome (or something very close to it)? Note - the site is being developed on WP. I'm not sure if that changes anything.
2. Once it is done, how do I add Project Information to the overlay?

Comment: make a div with with width:0 and height:0. When the button is clicked, resize it to 100% x 100% with an animation and use innerHTML to add content. Or you can pre-add content and hide it with display:none. when visible, just show it

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5as6y58a/ (vanilla JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small pen demonstrating how you can achieve this using CSS and very little plain Javascript:

https://codepen.io/Tauka/pen/OjEQzE

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: width 2s ease-out;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Important moments:

- .overlay must have width: 0 and position: fixed
- .content must have width in absolute measure, i.e. px/rem/em

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On button click add class active to .element and thats it

```
.element {
   bottom: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: -100%;
   position: fixed;
   right: auto;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   transition: left .3s ease-in;
}

.element.active {
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find a good example on the W3School web site.
Look at that https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp.

You can see on that site the almost exact same effect. I give the example code just here :

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>

</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```